# Assigning module function returns

Tags: python, function, global-variables, python-module

I'm relatively new to Python. I'm working on a script that will reassign a numerical representation of a digit found in a string to its alphabetical counterpart. Because the function is relatively large in size, I'm adding it as a module to the script.

I'm having some issues getting the object back from the imported function. I would like to use the returned object, but it seems to be coming back as None. I've looked into global variables, but I don't know if that's the right direction.

Here is what I've been working with:

```
...
import numassign
for i in CharacterKey: # i is '0'
    if i.isdigit():        
        FoundInt = numassign.NumberAssignment(input = i)
        CharacterKeyList.append(FoundInt)
        raw_input('{} reassigned to {}'.format(FoundInt, i))
    else:
        CharacterKeyList.append(i)
...
```

Here is the referenced module (numassign):

```
...
def NumberAssignment(input):
    if input == 0:
        FoundInt = 'Zero'
        return FoundInt
...
```

Currently returning FoundInt as None.

```
None reassigned to 0
```

How can I cross-reference objects from a module function? I'd rather not clutter up my code with functions if I could import them from a referenced module.

Comment: Don't edit your question to include the solution. Simply accept the answer to show that the question is resolved.

Comment: I hadn't been able to accept an answer until now. I will from now on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are testing for an integer, put are passing in a string.

They may *print* the same, but integers and strings never test as equal in Python. Test for the string instead:

```
if input == '0':
```

Because your `if input == 0` fails for `input = '0'`, your function never reaches a `return` statement, leaving Python to return the default `None` instead.

Comment: Of course. That's why its returning None. I'll test it correctly.

Comment: Thank you for the record breaking response. Returning object correctly. Added code to original post.